# Multiple radio-buttons in listview gets selected even if I select one button after scrolling

Tags: android, xml, listview, radio-button, android-arrayadapter

I have a list of cards-views which I am rendering, in each card there is information about that particular route and `radio button` which when clicked

1. should give me the position of the route form the complete list of routes
2. when clicked on different radio button previous one should be toggled and the one selected should be selected

Problem I am facing

when I select lets say 3rd radio button it selects 3rd items when the list renders the next views which is how the arrayadapter works. even though In my listview I have used `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"`  still its not selecting single radio button.

Here is the image also go see what the problem is exactly
[image]

my RouteAdapter class whee I am trying to check which radio-button is pressed

```
class RouteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RouteItem> {

    private Context mContext;

    RouteAdapter(Activity context, List<RouteItem> routes) {
        super(context, 0, routes);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            // we are passing false as we don't want to attach it to view just yet,
            // first set the proper name and details then set it.
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.route_view, parent, false);
        }
        // getting the route at that position
        RouteItem route = getItem(position);

        ......

        final RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
        //todo: fix radio button to save prefs
        rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RouteItem route = getItem(position);
                Log.d("RouteAdapter.class", "getView: "+ route.getRoute_id());
                rb.toggle();
            }
        });
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

my activity_view_route.xml where I am rendering all the routeItems

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/add_route"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        tools:context="com.sjain.routeplanner.ViewRouteActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/teal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my route_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/route_name"
                    android:id="@+id/view_name"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/endpoints"
                    android:id="@+id/view_start"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view_name"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:text="@string/view_waypoints"
                    android:id="@+id/waypoints"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/view_start"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/endpoints"
                    android:id="@+id/view_end"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/waypoints"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/view_map"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/view_end"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                    android:text="@string/view_map"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/view_id"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My routeItem class

```
class RouteItem {


    private String route_name;
    private String start_point;
    private String end_point;
    private String route_id;
    private  ArrayList<String> waypoints;
    private  ArrayList<String> waypoint_name;

    RouteItem(String route_name, String route_id, String start_point, String end_point, ArrayList<String> waypoints, ArrayList<String> waypoint_name) {
        this.route_name = route_name;
        this.route_id = route_id;
        this.start_point = start_point;
        this.end_point = end_point;
        this.waypoints = waypoints;
        this.waypoint_name = waypoint_name;
    }

    String getRoute_name() {
        return route_name;
    }

    String getStart_point() {
        return start_point.split(";")[0];
    }

    String getEnd_point() {
        return end_point.split(";")[0];
    }

    String getEnd_point_coordinate() {
        return end_point.split(";")[1];
    }

    String getStart_point_coordinate() {
        return start_point.split(";")[1];
    }

    String getRoute_id() {
        return route_id;
    }

    ArrayList<String> getWaypoints() {
        return waypoints;
    }

    ArrayList<String> getWaypoint_name() {
        return waypoint_name;
    }

}
```

I know there is something like radio-group also but that seems to be out of option here since the list is generated dynamically depending on the number of routes obtained form the server. My problem is similar to this question [Android Radio buttons in a custom listview changes its state when we scroll the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842599/android-radio-buttons-in-a-custom-listview-changes-its-state-when-we-scroll-the) but this is also not properly answered.

If someone can please let me know how to fix this issue and just get the position of the card which is selected.

Comment: You have to use a model class to set listview row and in that model class you have to define function to set radio button behaviour. So on click of any radio button, change other buttons behaviour and call  notifyDataSetChanged() after changing behaviour.

Comment: in my routeadapter class I am setting the radiobutton on click functionnality, but as I said when I click on radio button it selects all the 3rd item which is rendered by arrayadapter if i selct 3rd item as mentioned in the description

Comment: Yes, this problem will be solved if you will use model class for this.

Comment: ok, though as you can already see I have `RouteItem` model class but how to incorporate the changes for radiobutton in it as well, can you please share some code snippet I am new to android

Comment: Ok. Share your RouteItem class. I will tell you changes.

Comment: I posted answer for your question. Please check it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: I think my answer here will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849763/show-or-hide-widget-in-listview-when-checkbox-is-checked-or-unchecked-android/40880146#40880146

Comment: @warl0ck Do you want to select only one radio button from listview right?

Comment: yes, but as i scroll the list others are also getting selected

Comment: I posted my answer refer it may be it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092991/only-select-only-one-radio-button-from-listview/40908319#40908319

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First of all change your RouteItem class as :

```
class RouteItem {


    private String route_name;
    private String start_point;
    private String end_point;
    private String route_id;
    private  ArrayList<String> waypoints;
    private  ArrayList<String> waypoint_name;
    private String radioButtonState = "unSelected";

    RouteItem(String route_name, String route_id, String start_point, String end_point, ArrayList<String> waypoints, ArrayList<String> waypoint_name) {
        this.route_name = route_name;
        this.route_id = route_id;
        this.start_point = start_point;
        this.end_point = end_point;
        this.waypoints = waypoints;
        this.waypoint_name = waypoint_name;
    }

    String getRoute_name() {
        return route_name;
    }

    String getStart_point() {
        return start_point.split(";")[0];
    }

    String getEnd_point() {
        return end_point.split(";")[0];
    }

    String getEnd_point_coordinate() {
        return end_point.split(";")[1];
    }

    String getStart_point_coordinate() {
        return start_point.split(";")[1];
    }

    String getRoute_id() {
        return route_id;
    }

    ArrayList<String> getWaypoints() {
        return waypoints;
    }

    ArrayList<String> getWaypoint_name() {
        return waypoint_name;
    }

    public String getRadioButtonState() {
        return radioButtonState;
    }

    public void setRadioButtonState(String radioButtonState) {
        this.radioButtonState = radioButtonState;
    }

}
```

Now update your adapter.

```
    class RouteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RouteItem> {

    private Context mContext;
    List<RouteItem> routes;
    RouteAdapter(Activity context, List<RouteItem> routes) {
        super(context, 0, routes);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.routes = routes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            // we are passing false as we don't want to attach it to view just yet,
            // first set the proper name and details then set it.
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.route_view, parent, false);
        }
        // getting the route at that position
        RouteItem route = getItem(position);

        ......

        final RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
        //todo: fix radio button to save prefs

         if(route.getRadioButtonState().equals("unSelected")){
           rb.setSelected(false);
        }
        else{
           rb.setSelected(true);
        }


        rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RouteItem route = getItem(position);
                Log.d("RouteAdapter.class", "getView: "+ route.getRoute_id());
                rb.toggle();

                if(rb.isSelected()){
                     route.setRadioButtonState("selected");
                }
                else {
                     route.setRadioButtonState("unSelected");
                }

                for(int i=0; i<routes.size(); i++){
                    if(i != position){
                       routes.get(i).setRadioButtonState("unSelected");
                    }
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but still If i select one radio button and then select another both of them are selected , but ideally first one should have been unselected, which is not happening here

Comment: still the same issue, also I dont have access to all the routes here so that might also be the problem, currently I tested it by manually putting the number of routes, but still I can select all of the route cards

Comment: I think after the for loop, all those radiobutton should also be set to `checked(false)` which is missing and there is no reference to do it also

Comment: I even tried like `if(route.getRadioButtonState().equals("unSelected")){rb.setSelected(true); }else{ rb.setSelected(false); } `  but still none of the radio buttons were selected though as per logic here all of them should have been selected, I think I am even able to set or change the state of radio button from code

Comment: You have to pass all routes in constructor of adapter.

Comment: just for this purpose `routes.size()` as currently to test I did `16` which is current length, still doesn't work I can select multiple radio buttons

Comment: I forgot to initialize i as zero in for loop. Did you change that?

Comment: yes, obviously, thats not the problem, thing there is no change still, I can select all the radio buttons still